# GatsbyJS - How to query longtext Contentful fields in GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, markdown, graphql, contentful, gatsby

I ran into a problem querying a field of type "long text" from contentful.

I know the Contentful long text field is actually markdown. So I installed the gatsby-transformer-remark plugin, which I presumed I need.

Here's my GraphQL query:

```
  query getStoreById($relativeUrl: String!) {
    contentfulStore(relativeUrl: { eq: $relativeUrl }) {
      relativeUrl
      shopPageTitle
      mainPageTextContent {
        mainPageTextContent
      }
    }
  }
```

The console still shows:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {childMarkdownRemark}).
```

Something to do with that error message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query will look something like:

`query getStoreById($relativeUrl: String!) {
    contentfulStore(relativeUrl: { eq: $relativeUrl }) {
      relativeUrl
      shopPageTitle
      mainPageTextContent {
        childMarkdownRemark {
          html
        }
      }
    }
  }`

If you haven't learned how to use Graph*i*QL yet, try opening it at localhost:8000/___graphql! It's your best friend for learning how to query your Contentful schema.